# using grep commands to find a duplicate id within a json file

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, grep

I am looking for a way to use grep on a linux server to find duplicate json records, is it possible to have a grep to search for duplicate id's in the example below ?

so the grep would return: 01

```
{
 "book": [

  {
     "id": "01",
     "language": "Java",
     "edition": "third",
     "author": "Herbert Schildt"
  },
  {
     "id": "02",
     "language": "Java",
     "edition": "third",
     "author": "Herbert Schildt"
  },
  {
     "id": "03",
     "language": "Java",
     "edition": "third",
     "author": "Herbert Schildt"
  },
  {
     "id": "01",
     "language": "Java",
     "edition": "third",
     "author": "Herbert Schildt"
  },

  {
     "id": "04",
     "language": "C++",
     "edition": "second",
     "author": "E.Balagurusamy"
  }

 ]
}
```

Comment: follow up on your comment to Barmar's answer below: how about you provide the actual format, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, discarding any whitespace from the JSON strings I can offer this if `awk` is acceptable - `hutch` being the formatted chunk of JSON above in a file.

I use `tr` to remove any whitespace, use `,` as a field separator in awk; iterate over the one long lines elements with a for-loop, do some pattern-matching in awk to isolate ID fields and increment an array for each matched ID. At the end of processing I iterate over the array and print ID's that have more than one match.

Here your data:

```
$ cat hutch 
{
 "book": [

  {
     "id": "01",
     "language": "Java",
     "edition": "third",
     "author": "Herbert Schildt"
  },
  {
     "id": "02",
     "language": "Java",
     "edition": "third",
     "author": "Herbert Schildt"
  },
  {
     "id": "03",
     "language": "Java",
     "edition": "third",
     "author": "Herbert Schildt"
  },
  {
     "id": "01",
     "language": "Java",
     "edition": "third",
     "author": "Herbert Schildt"
  },

  {
     "id": "04",
     "language": "C++",
     "edition": "second",
     "author": "E.Balagurusamy"
  }

 ]
}
```

And here the finding of dupes:

```
$ tr -d '[:space:]' <hutch |  awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/"id":/){a[gensub(/^.*"id":"([0-9]+)"$/, "\\1","1",$i)]++}}}END{for(i in a){if(a[i]>1){print i}}}'
01
```

Answer (score 2):

use `grep` along with `uniq`.

```
grep '"id":' filename | sort | uniq -d
```

The `-d` option only prints duplicates.

However, this depends on the JSON being laid out neatly. To handle more general formatting, I recommend you use the `jq` utility.

Comment: This assumes the JSON is regularly laid out with all the `id` fields identically formatted alone on a line.

Comment: @Barmar On the example JSON above this works, however on my actual JSON it does not, I presume this is the mentioned formatting issue, I will not be able to install any additional tools onto the server.

Answer (score 2):

A `jq`-based approach:

```sh
jq -r '.book[].id' < in.json | sort | uniq -d
01
```

This should work even for minified JSON files with no newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Perl one-liner to extract the numeric ids, then `sort | uniq -d` to print only the duplicates (as in the answer by *Barmar*):

This assumes that the id key/value pair is on the same line, but disregards whitespace (or lack of whitespace) anywhere on the line (leading, trailing, and in between):

```
perl -lne 'print for /"id":\s*"(\d+)"/' in.json | sort | uniq -d
```

This makes no assumptions (disregards whitespace and newlines). Note that it reads the entire json file into memory (using the `-0777` command line switch):

```
perl -0777 -nE 'say for /"id":\s*"(\d+)"/g' in.json | sort | uniq -d
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-E` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file. Also enables all optional features. Here, enables `say`.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-0777` : Slurp files whole.

The regex uses this modifier:
`/g` : Multiple matches.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)